# $f(x)=\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x,y)dy$ is uniformly convergent on $ (c,d)$, f(x,y) is continuous,is f(x) unformly continuous?

Tags: calculus

$f(x)=\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x,y)dy$ is uniformly convergent on $(c,d)$, and $f(x,y)$ is continuous,can one deduce that $f(x)$ is unformly continuous on $(c,d)$?

For example: $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{xy^2}$, we know that it is continuous on $(0,1)\times(1,\infty)$, and 
$$f(x)=\int_{1}^{∞}\frac{1}{xy^2}dy=\frac{1}{x}$$
Which is not uniformly continuos , and that improper integral is not uniformly convergent  .

What makes it different from the functional sequence $f_n(x)$ is that , $f_n(x)$ can be write into the form 
$$f_n(x)=g(x)+h_n(x)$$ 
then just let the $g$ be a non-unformly continuous function is OK. But one cannot write so in the improper integral , seems likes that they are bounded together.

So which makes me think , it is a right conclusion , but I don't know how to prove , thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "$f(x)=\dots$ is uniformly convergent on $(a,\infty)\times(c,d)$"?

Comment: @user10354138 My apologize , I had re-posted it , and corrected some mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

For example, let $f(x,y)=g(x)e^{-y}$, $a=0$.  Then the condition $f\colon(c,d)\times(a,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ continuous reduces to $g\colon(c,d)\to\mathbb{R}$ being continuous, and $\int_a^\infty f(-,y)\,\mathrm{d}y$ uniformly converges to $g$ amounts to $g$ being bounded.  There are of course such $g$ which are not uniformly continuous, e.g., $g(x)=\sin(1/x)$ on $(0,1)$.

Comment: thank you very much ， I know where I was wrong !